# 2 domains, same website in plesk

Tags: plesk

I have a domain with a SSL at `https://www.domain1.com`.

I want that `http://www.domain2.com` shows the same website as domain1 (same website folder).

I've tried with domain alias in Plesk but it's redirecting to `https://www.domain1.com`.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You want domain2 to effectively bypass your security certificate?!

Comment: I've solved the issue the problem was the default domain for the IP that corresponds to the first domain. Now the problem would be how to enable SNI so SSL cert applies to both domains. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With Plesk you can set a default certificate for all domains to use, but unless it's a UCC SSL, you'll get a browser warning for all but the one it was issued for.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening as a result of a incorrect htaccess file, you are most likely have an entry somewhere that has your full domain name of the original. Edit all traces of the orginal htaccess file, however you will need one command that is set to domain1 because of the SSL. You might be using something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change it too something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```